# How to access object's members from an array of object tuples

Tags: scala, apache-spark, tuples

Object class is

```
class VertexAttributes(val m: Boolean, n: Any){

        val rootParentCustNumber: String = if(n == null) "Was Null" else n.toString
        val firstMsgFlg = m

}
```

I have an RDD of this object's type:

```
scala> myGraph.vertices
res92: org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexRDD[VertexAttributes] = VertexRDDImpl[2280] at RDD at VertexRDD.scala:57
```

Filtering on the RDD, I get the following:

```
scala> res92.filter{case(k,m) => k == 964088677}.collect
res94: Array[(org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId, VertexAttributes)] = Array((964088677,VertexAttributes@2612b83f))
```

How can I access `VertexAttributes@2612b83f.rootParentCustNumber` in `Array((964088677,VertexAttributes@2612b83f))`

I have tried `res92.filter{case(k,m) => k == 964088677}.map{case Array(k,m)=> m.rootParentCustNumber}`

But I get the following error:

```
<console>:243: error: pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
 found   : Array[T]
 required: (org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId, VertexAttributes)
    (which expands to)  (Long, VertexAttributes)
       res92.filter{case(k,m) => k == 964088677}.map{case Array(k,m)=> m.rootParentCustNumber}
                                                               ^
```

Comment: Same as the `filter` stage: `.map{ case (k, m) => m.rootParentCustNumber }`

Comment: But I need to filter first to get the object I want.

Comment: You sill can filter before. The filtering stage doesn't change the type of the RDD. So you can pipe the returned RDD of the filter stage with a map stage: `res92.filter{ case(k, m) => k == 964088677 }.map{ case (k, m) => m.rootParentCustNumber }`

Comment: Thank you. Could you please post that answer, so I can select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filtering stage doesn't change the type of the RDD ( which is `RDD[(Long, VertexAttributes)]`).

So you can pipe the returned RDD of the filter stage with a map stage and work with each record the same way you did in the filtering stage:

```
res92
  .filter{ case (k, m) => k == 964088677 }
  .map{ case (k, m) => m.rootParentCustNumber }
```

---

I think you've been misled by the collect stage which transforms the RDD into an Array.